# Netmiko: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv_ready'

Tags: python-3.x, cisco-ios

I am trying to connect to Cisco Router to pull some information and I am receiving the following error when I run my code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cisco_auto_back_up_v4.py", line 72, in 
    redispatch(net_connect, device_type=target_device['device_type'])
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 208, in redispatch
    obj.session_preparation()
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/cisco/cisco_ios.py", line 16, in session_preparation
    self._test_channel_read(pattern=r'[>#]')
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 791, in _test_channel_read
    new_data += self._read_channel_timing()
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 494, in _read_channel_timing
    new_data = self.read_channel()
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 395, in read_channel
    output = self._read_channel()
  File "/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 373, in _read_channel
    if self.remote_conn.recv_ready():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv_ready'

Here is my code:

```
    #!/home/ipautowppprod/.pyenv/shims/python

# cisco_auto_back_up_v4

from netmiko import ConnectHandler, redispatch
from netmiko import NetMikoAuthenticationException, NetMikoTimeoutException
import datetime
import sys
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

target_info = sys.argv[1].split(',')
ipmon_info = sys.argv[2].split(',')

target_info = [x.strip() for x in target_info]
ipmon_info = [x.strip() for x in ipmon_info]

target_device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': target_info[0],
    "host": target_info[1],
    'username': target_info[2],
    'password': target_info[3],
    'secret': target_info[4]
}

ipmon = {
    'device_type': 'linux',
    'ip': ipmon_info[0],
    'username': ipmon_info[1],
    'password': ipmon_info[2]
}

try:
    print("Attempting to Connect...")
    # Connect to ipmon
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ipmon)
    print(net_connect.find_prompt())

    net_connect.write_channel("ssh {}@{}\n".format(target_device["username"],
                                                   target_device["ip"]))
    time.sleep(1)
    output = net_connect.read_channel()

    print(output)

    if "RSA" in output:
        net_connect.write_channel("yes\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        output = net_connect.read_channel()
        print(output)
    if "user" in output:
        net_connect.write_channel(target_device["username"] + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        output = net_connect.read_channel()
    if "password" in output:
        net_connect.write_channel(target_device["password"] + "\n")
        time.sleep(5)
        output = net_connect.read_channel()
    if "password" in output:
        print("Wrong credentials.")
        sys.exit(1)
    elif "refused" in output:
        net_connect.disconnect()
        print("Connection Refused")
    else:
        net_connect.disconnect()

    # Connect to device
    redispatch(net_connect, device_type=target_device['device_type'])
    CMD = net_connect.send_command_timing('show running-config')

    # Converts CMD output to a string
    cmd_output = str(CMD.stdout)

except NetMikoAuthenticationException as autom_err:
    print(autom_err)
    sys.exit(1)

except NetMikoTimeoutException as timeout_err:
    print(timeout_err)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to step through your code execution using a debugger, but it looks like when you get to the redispatch call, that your net_connect object is no longer connected (i.e. net_connect.remote_conn has been set to None).

This makes me think that the disconnect() in the elif or else clause was possibly called. You probably should raise an exception in those cases (or sys.exit() ) as your program won't be able to continue if either of those happen.

Comment: [name@domain.com  ~]$
DEBUG:netmiko:In strip_ansi_escape_codes
DEBUG:netmiko:repr = '[name@domain.com  ~]$'
DEBUG:netmiko:new_output = [name@domain.com  ~]$
DEBUG:netmiko:repr = '[name@domain.com  ~]$'
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'ssh name@10.199.217.1\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
[name@domain.com  ~]$ ssh name@10.199.217.1

DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'exit\n'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
[name@srv01 test_scripts]$